# Computing basis of $\mathrm{Pic}(\bar{X})$ for a Del Pezzo surface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, picard-group

Say we are given a degree 2 del Pezzo $X$ given by $w^2=Q(x,y,z)$ where $Q(x,y,z)$ is degree 4. We can compute the exceptional lines by computing the 28 bitangent lines of $Q$ and look at the preimages of them. Suppose that for some given $Q$, we have found the explicit equations of the bitangent lines and exceptional lines, what is an effective/efficient way to find a basis of $\operatorname{Pic}(\bar{X})$? Do I have to compute the intersection number for all of them?

Comment: Suppose $L$ and $L^\prime$ are bitangents with preimages $E_1+E_2$ and $E_1^\prime + E_2^\prime$ respectively. If the intersection point of $L$ and $L^\prime$ is not on $Q$, then each of the $E_i$ will be disjoint from one of the $E_i^\prime$. You can use this to build up a set of 7 disjoint exceptional curves fairly quickly. Lastly you need, for example, another exceptional curve that intersects precisely 2 of your 7 chosen curves. I'm not sure how efficient this is but it seems quicker than computing intersection numbers of every pair of exceptional curves.